# Predict arguments of indicator function or the value the indicator function itself

Tags: neural-network, training

I have an evenly-spaced timeseries $a_1, a_2, a_3,..., a_n$ and a function $f_k=\mathbf 1(a_k-a_{k-5})$, where $\mathbf 1$ is the unit step function.

I want to predict $f_k$ using $a_1, a_2, a_3,..., a_{k-5}$, that is, I want to predict if $a_k>a_{k-5}$, given the values $a_1..., a_{k-5}$ .

**My question is:**

Is it better to construct and train an ANN to:

- directly predict values of $f_k$

OR

- predict values of $a_k$, and then apply $f_k$ to the result?

Comment: $f_k$ is predicted on the basis of $\{(f_j, a_j) | j < k\}$ so they're similar, but the loss function should obviously be based on $f_k$ -- your objective.

Comment: @Emre, I could simply predict $a_k$ on the basis of $\{a_j|j<(k-5)\}$ and postprocess the result to get $f_k$. I imagine that, in terms of numerical behaviour, training and quality of the result, one or other could be better, couldn't it?

Comment: Don't predict $a_k$, because that would optimize the wrong thing. You want to classify, not regress. You could get $a_k$ wildly wrong and still predict $f_k$ perfectly. Reflect on that ...